# Send UTF-8 string from Android to C#

Tags: c#, android, utf

I've been trying to accomplish a simple text transmission from my Android app to my C# server (asmx server), sending the simplest string - and for some reason it never works. My Android code is as following (assume that the variable 'message' holds the string as received from an EditText, which is UTF-16 as far as I'm concerned):

```
httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(POST_MESSAGE_ADDRESS);
byte[] messageBytes = message.getBytes("utf-8");
builder.addPart("message", new StringBody(messageBytes.toString()));
HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
post.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
```

So I get something simple for my message, say a 10 bytes array. In my server, I have a function set to that specific address; its code is:

```
string message = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["message"];
byte[] test = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
```

Now after that line the byte array ('test') has the exact same value as the result of the ToString() function I called in the app. Question is, how do I convert it to normal UTF-8 text to display?

Note: I have tried sending the string normally as a string content, but as far as I understood the default coding is ASCII so I got a lot of question marks.

**Edit**: Now I'm looking for some conversions solutions and trying them, but my question is also if there's a simpler way to do that (perhaps BinaryBody in the android, or different coding?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in following lines:

```
byte[] messageBytes = message.getBytes("utf-8");
builder.addPart("message", new StringBody(messageBytes.toString()));
```

First you are transforming your `UTF-16` string `message` into `UTF-8` encoded `messageBytes` only to convert them back to `UTF-16` string in next line. And there you are using `StringBody` constructor that will use ASCII encoding as default.

You should replace those lines with:

```
builder.addPart("message", new StringBody(message, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Very quick and helpful :)